# Using inline C# code with serverside html tags

Tags: c#, asp.net, inline-code

is it possible to use inline `c#` code (i.e. `<%# someFunction(someParameter) %>`) in serverside html tags? The reason I ask is that I do this sort of thing with a regular `<div>` tag and it works well, but as soon as I add the following code it passes the code through with the output html to the client.

Here's my original div tag:

```
<div class="invoiceUnselected" onclick='select(this,<%# Eval("ID") %>);' >
```

which passes through:

```
<div class="invoiceSelected" onclick="select(this,271856);">
```

and the new:

```
<div id="divInvoiceHeader" runat="server" class="invoiceUnselected"
     onclick='select(this,<%# Eval("ID") %>);' >
```

passes through

```
<div id="ctl00_bodyCPH_accRenewals_Pane_0_header_divInvoiceHeader"
     class="invoiceUnselected" onclick="select(this,<%# Eval("ID") %>);">
```

Comment: You will need to edit your question, it doesn't appear to be displaying correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
onclick='<%#"select(this, "+Eval("ID").ToString()+")" %>'
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option to make this a bit neater:

```
onclick='<%# Eval("ID","select(this,{0})") %>'
```